# SVG: zoom gesture with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, gesture-recognition, gesture

my webpage consits of a large svg drawing with embedded images and links.

The user shoud zoom in by clicking the mouse and moving the cursor to the right. this is similar to photosho cs5 zoom gesture.

How can I implement that gesture to zoom in the SVG picture using javascript? Possibly with libs raphael or jQuery SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first example/demo in http://www.evanbyrne.com/article/super-gestures-jquery-plugin and this gallery http://random.friggeri.net/jquery-gestures/ maybe it will help you.

Comment: thanks! additionally to your links, I think it could be implemented without using a library too. I have to see.